# C# delegate with params

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a validate method that called some other implements:

```
public ValidationResult Validate(Some arg) {
    var errors = new List<ValidationError>();

    validate1(arg, errors);
    if (errors.Count > 0) {
        return ValidationResult.Failed(errors);
    }

    validate2(arg, other, errors);
    if (errors.Count > 0) {
        return ValidationResult.Failed(errors);
    }

    validate3(arg, other2, errors);
    if (errors.Count > 0) {
        return ValidationResult.Failed(errors);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Succeess();
}
```

I want some way to make the code like below, use for loop to invoke each validator:

```
public ValidationResult Validate(Some arg) {
    var errors = new List<ValidationError>();

    var validators = new [] {
        validate1(arg, errors),
        validate2(arg, other, errors),
        validate3(arg, other2, errors)
    };

    foreach (var validator in validators) {
        validator.invoke();
        if (errors.Count > 0) {
            return ValidationResult.Failed(errors);
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success();
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What is `other` and `other2`? Does `validate` have 2 overloads?

Comment: Use an array or list of lambdas. Microsoft's documentation available online is your friend in case you have not used them before.

Comment: @Sweeper There no overload, it's three different method, them have different parameter list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this

```
var validators = new Action[]  {
    ()=>validate1(arg, errors),
    ()=>validate2(arg, other, errors),
    ()=>validate3(arg, other2, errors)
};

foreach (var v in  validators)
    v();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a common interface for the validators and implement a class for each usecase.

```
public interface IValidator {
    ValidationResult Invoke();
}

public class Validator1 : IValidator {
    private string _arg;
    private List<ValidationError> _errors;

    Validator1(string arg, List<ValidationError> errors) {
        _arg = arg; 
       _errors = errors
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate() {
        if (_errors.Count > 0) {
            return ValidationResult.Failed(_errors);
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success();
    }
}
```

Then you can work with a list of IValidator instances.

```
public ValidationResult Validate(Some arg) {
    var errors = new List<ValidationError>();

    var validators = new IValidator[] {
        new Validator1(arg, errors),
        new Validator2(arg, other, errors),
        new Validator3(arg, other2, errors)
    };

    foreach (var validator in validators) {
        var result = validator.Invoke();
        if (result != ValidationResult.Success()) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I consider implementing validation in Fluent-like style:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(T obj);
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> ValidateAll(IEnumerable<T> obj);
}


public class SomeTypeValidator : IValidator<SomeType>
{
    private readonly IValidator<SomeNestedType> _validator1;
    public SomeTypeValidator(IValidator<SomeNestedType> validator1)
    {
        _validator1 = validator1;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(SomeType obj)
    {
        yield return Error("My first error");
        foreach(var e in _validator1.Validate(obj.val1))
        {
             yield return e;
        }
        /*whatever you desire goes here*/
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationError> ValidateAll(IEnumerable<SomeType> objs)
    {
        return objs.SelectMany(Validate);
    }
}
```

Then some useful extension:

```
public static void ThrowIfInvalid(this IEnumerable<ValidationError> errors)
{
    if(errors == null)
       return;
    var e = errors.ToList();
    if(e.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception(\*use 'e' here to form exception*\);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in code I call it like this:

```
_validator.Validate(new SomeType()).ThrowIfInvalid();
```

This way you will free yourself from those lists/packs of errors all over the place and just redirect validation error streams to whatever other validator you desire. Also you always can stop validation at some point, by calling `yield break` and will be able to create ansamble from them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tym32167 !

And I have some additional about async:

```
        var validations = new Func<Task>[]
        {
            async () => await ValidateAsync(arg, other, errors)
        };

        foreach (var validation in validations)
        {
            await validation();
            if (errors.Count > 0)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Failed(errors);
            }
        }
```